# How to change vue.js components data outside scope

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to change vue.js data outside the default export statement. Given the example below, how would I go about doing that?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h6 class="font-weight-normal mb-3">{{ name }}</h6>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: ""
        }
    }
}

let changeName = (name) => {
    //How do I change the name data property here
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is typically done via [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) or [slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots).

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done because [Vue Loader will only look for stuff inside the default export](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#script). The question is what is your use case because there should be a way to acheive what you want in a way that is compatible with how Vue works.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the component to a variable/constant, you should be able to simply trigger the proxy setter of the data object or with component-level methods.

```js
const component = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      name: "Initial value."
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    changeName(newName) {
      this.name = newName;
    }
  }
});

// Mount it to an element (for demo purposes)
component.$mount('#app');

document.getElementById('btn-setter').onclick = function() {
  component.name = 'Changed with SETTER';
};

document.getElementById('btn-method').onclick = function() {
  component.changeName('Changed with METHOD');
};

// Uncomment this to start exporting it.
// export default component;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h6 class="font-weight-normal mb-3">{{ name }}</h6>
  
  <button id="btn-setter">Change with setter</button>
  <button id="btn-method">Change with method</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write any function you want in the page outside of the component (or export statement) but you would need to invoke it in your `methods` section or somewhere in the component. I use this for functions that create default values, instead of importing them from outside just write a function `initVal = () => someVal` then in the `data` or `computed` or somewhere reference `initVal` (no this).